# Crashlytics dashboard doesn't show original Exception but only triggered Exception from new Activity

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have a List Activity A that calls another Detail Activity B.

In Activity B I can call Activity C that is triggered by some button press and this one crashes.

Because of this, Logcat briefly shows the Exception thrown from Activity C (The real error) but then the Logcat logging gets cleared and gets replaced by the new crash of Activity A.

The Activity A crash is just a response to the original crash and I need to solve the original crash.

When I record the Logcat output with a phone I briefly see the original error, and can solve it. However, the problem that we are having is shown on the Crashlytics dashboard and this is only showing the Activity A error.

The PID is different but both exceptions occur on the Main thread.

```
2019-09-26 14:08:21.965 4860-4860/nl.someCompany.acc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nl.someCompany.acc, PID: 4860
```

Comment: Please read the problem more carefully. I cannot debug because this issue occurs on production and i only have crashlytics daahboard that shows the wrong exception of activity A

Comment: Using some custom logging around the time of the error in Activity C might help you get more info out of this crash as well: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html

Comment: You don't know when this crash occurs, that is the problem. With Activity C I'm referring to a lot of code functionality.